# Just installed Windows 8 Pro and transparent windows are gone?

Tags: windows-8

I've installed and updated all my drivers but the windows have no transparency on them, the task bar does have transparency however.

Is this normal for Windows 8 Pro or should I be able to enable transparent windows somewhere?

*There is no 'enable transparency' in 'colour and apperance' window...

Comment: This is normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transparency has not been removed, but has been deprecated.  There is a complicated work-around available [here](http://www.intowindows.com/enable-aero-glass-in-windows-8/)

Comment: So this option: http://cdn.ghacks.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/enable-transparency-550x405.jpg ('enable transparency' is not visible to anyone anymore?)

Comment: @USlackr The hack is only applicable for machines that have upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 8 and not clean installs of Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Aero Glass is gone](https://web.archive.org/web/20151118205740/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/05/18/creating-the-windows-8-user-experience.aspx). An [user claimed he hacked this](https://web.archive.org/web/20130828081811/http://link6155.deviantart.com/art/Metro-335834397) and will provide a theme at the end of this year.

> Tell me how you did that transparancy
> I was trying to get it for weeks and weeks with all sorts of margin, padding, placement hacks etc etc
> **It's a secret for now**
> I can't go into much information, but if you would like to know more, send me a note

[image]